# Parrafo en FPDF php

Tags: php, fpdf

Estoy intentando crear un PDF con esta librería, pero cuando inserto un párrafo, no consigo ajustarlo al ancho de la página, siempre se sale de los márgenes...

Este es mi código:

```
function escribeDetalles(){
    $this->SetFont('Helvetica','',10);
    $this->SetXY(6, 50);
    //texto centrado los ultimos numeros(0,0) es si queremos dibujar la caja
    $this->MultiCell(160, 140, utf8_decode($_POST["detallesArticulo"]));
    //$this->Cell(150, 125, $_POST["detallesArticulo"],0,0,'C');
}
```

y este es el resultado

[image: Resultado PDF]

No consigo ajustarlo... es una textarea de html donde recojo el contenido

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución al final ha sido esta.

```
function escribeDetalles(){

    $this->SetFont('Helvetica','',10);
    $this->SetXY(6, 130);
    $this->MultiCell(190, 6, utf8_decode($_POST["detallesArticulo"]));
}
```

Hay que tener cuidado con setXY() porque es donde se escribe la celda y a parte, el segundo parámetro de multicell que es la altura de la linea, osea el interlineado, debe ser acorde, mi problema era que pensaba que era la altura donde quería escribir el texto...